# iOS Testing asynchronous method performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest, xctestexpectation

I'm trying to write a performance test for a API request method. When I run it without measureBlock it runs ok, but when I use it as performance test I got the error message:

> *** Assertion failure in -[Performance waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler:], /SourceCache/XCTest_Sim/XCTest-7701/XCTestFramework/Classes/XCTestCase+AsynchronousTesting.m:236
>   /Users/iphonetest03/Desktop/shootr-ios/Tests/Performance.m:42: error: -[Performance testPerformanceExample] : failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "API violation - call made to wait without any expectations having been set."

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.
Here it's my code:

```
    @interface Performance : XCTestCase
       @property (nonatomic,strong)    XCTestExpectation *expectation;
       @property (nonatomic)           BOOL              serverResponse;
    @end

    @implementation Performance

       - (void)setUp {
          [super setUp];
          self.expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Server response"];
       }

       - (void)tearDown {
          [super tearDown];
       }

       - (void)testPerformanceExample {
          [self measureBlock:^{
             [ShotQueueManager singleton].sendingrequestor = self;
             [[ShotQueueManager singleton] createShotQueueWithComment:@"iOS Shot creation performance test." andPhotoBinary:nil shotParent:nil userNameParent:nil andDelegate:self];
             [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:25.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                   NSLog(@"Timeout Error: %@", error);
                }else{
                   XCTAssert(self.serverResponse);
                }
             }];
          }];
       }


       - (void)createShotResponseWithStatus:(BOOL)status andError:(NSError *)error {
          if (status && !error){
            self.serverResponse = YES;
            [self.expectation fulfill];
          }
       }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple testPerformance with XCTestCase objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145468/multiple-testperformance-with-xctestcase-objective-c)