# XCTest performance testing of POST API

Tags: ios, swift, performance-testing, xctest, xctestcase

I am implementing Unit Test for my iOS swift project. I want to implement performance test for the POST API which I had in my project, but I don't know how to implement that POST API. I have tested GET APIs and that give me desired results.

Here's the code what I am trying to implement

```
func testPerfromancePOSTAPI() {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: MY_URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: MY_SERVICE_PARA, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        self.measure {
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }
                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                        print("response JSON = \(json)")
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    XCTFail("Expectation Failed with error: %@", file: error as! StaticString);
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

When I run this test it passes successfully but doesn't print the response JSON and neither gives an error and shows that "Time 0.0000 sec (161% STDEV)", while running the same API in postman it takes few sec.
Please check and help me out this.

Comment: did u check whether the completion block gets executed? @vivek

Comment: @jegadeesh I put the debug point but it never comes in completion block.

Comment: Thats the problem. Are you sure your request is hitting the server? @Vivek

Comment: remove the self.measure code and and directly resume the task. I don't know whether the code inside self.measure will get executed.

Comment: @jegadeesh In that case it will execute the completion block , but it will consider as functional test and not as performance testing

Comment: I have similiar test case as yours and it works fine for me. Try using expectation in ur code to see whether the request takes too much time to get reponse @Vivek

Comment: Added an answer do check it @Vivek

Comment: @jegadeesh , yes sure let me check and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ur code as follows

```
 func testPerfromancePOSTAPI() {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: MY_URL)
    let expectations = expectation(description: "POST")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: MY_SERVICE_PARA, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    self.measure {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                    print("response JSON = \(json)")         expectations.fulfill()
                }
            } catch let error {
                XCTFail("Expectation Failed with error: %@", file: error as! StaticString);
            }
        })
        task.resume()
        self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                XCTFail("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Change the timeout value to a higher one, if u still not getting any responses.

Comment: I have tried this solutions and completion block called twice but I am getting error like 

1) failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "API violation - call made to wait without any expectations having been set error.
2) Assertion failure in -[XCTestExpectation fulfill]
3)Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'API violation - multiple calls made to -[XCTestExpectation fulfill] for POST.

I have also tried with higher timeout but error remains the same

Comment: Performance test will execute the measure block multiple times. try defining the expectation inside the measure block and follow this link for more information:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145468/multiple-testperformance-with-xctestcase-objective-c

Comment: I tried to define expectation inside the measure block and works perfect , thanks :-)

Comment: Long day isn't it..? :)

Comment: yup, takes so much hour

Answer (score 0):

Defining expectation inside the measure block will works to measure performance.

```
func testPostAPIFetchParseTime() {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: MY_URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: MY_SERVICE_PARA, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        self.measure {
            let expectations = self.expectation(description: "POST API performance check")
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }
                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                        print("response JSON = \(json)")
                        expectations.fulfill()
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    XCTFail("Expectation Failed with error: %@", file: error as! StaticString);
                }
            })
            task.resume()
            self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10.0) { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    XCTFail("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```